# "file format not recognized" when compiling CUDA code with nvcc and gcc using qmake

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, cuda, nvcc

I have to following two files in my project:

```
home/cuda_compilation_test/
    main.cpp
    libcudatest.cu
    cuda_compilation_test.pro
```

I am using QtCreator with qmake for compilation. However, when I am building the project using the project file shown below, I recieve a linking error **file format not recognized; treating as linker script**.
It nonetheless produces two object files in the debug directory

```
home/build-cuda_compilation_test-Desktop-Debug/
    main.o
    libcudatest.o
```

How can I

1. check, that the object file is indeed correctly produced and
2. include the seperately compiled libcudatest.o in the main project

For further reference, this is the compiler output

```
g++ -m64 -o cuda_compilation_test_2 libcudatest.o main.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lcudatest -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld:libcudatest.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:libcudatest.o:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cuda_compilation_test_2] Error 1
11:19:20: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
```

and the project file:

```
TEMPLATE =

# Files
SOURCES += main.cpp

OTHER_FILES += libcudatest.cu

LIBS += -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
LIBS += -lcudart -lcudatest

# CUDA path
CUDA_DIR = /usr/local/cuda
CUDA_CC = $$CUDA_DIR/bin/nvcc

# CUDA Setup
CUDA_SOURCES  = libcudatest.cu
NVCCINCLUDES +=
NVCCFLAGS     = --shared -arch sm_35 -Xcompiler -fPIC --ptxas-options=-v
INCLUDEPATH  +=
LIBS         +=


# Configuration of the Cuda compiler
# http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html#customizing
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    # Debug mode
    cuda_d.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda_d.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.o
    cuda_d.commands = $$CUDA_CC -D_DEBUG $$NVCCFLAGS $$NVCCINCLUDES $$LIBS -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
    cuda_d.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda_d
}
else {
# Release mode
    cuda.input = CUDA_SOURCES
    cuda.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.o
    cuda.commands = $$CUDA_CC $$NVCCFLAGS $$NVCCINCLUDES $$LIBS -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT} ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}
    cuda.dependency_type = TYPE_C
    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += cuda
}
```

I am trying to compile on linux.

Thank you very much for any help on this topic.

Comment: I don't know anything about qt or qmake. But I think the linker is getting tripped up by the fact that you are telling `nvcc` to compile the `libcudatest.cu` into a shared object (which would normally be in a `.so` file) with the `--shared` switch, but you are specifying an output file of `.o`. Try renaming your `libcudatest.o` to `libcudatest.so` and then repeat the link command with that change:  `g++ -m64 -o cuda_compilation_test_2 libcudatest.so main.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart -lcudatest -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread`  If it works, then it would confirm.

Comment: Were you able to make it work?